# How to create a counter that resets to zero at the end of the day in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have created a bulk mailer software as part of a project. I have added a counter to count the number of mails sent daily and once the limit is reached the mails are not sent. Now I want to automatically reset the counter at the end of the day.

Comment: Whats wrong with getting the current time and compare with last second or minute of today and reset the counter?  what you have tried so far?

Comment: you can use `DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") == "0:00:00 AM"` then reset the counter

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Why converting the DateTime into string to compare it? He wants to compare a DateTime. So i think a DateTime.Now.CompareTo(); makes more sense.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava your aproach will not work - for workin your line must be executed every seconds

Comment: Yup!! @Sebi it makes more sense. But it is only to give idea that is y it is a comment and not answer.

Comment: @Fabio: I do agree with you but the question is bit vague and not very clear thus we dont know if the application runs all the time or does it stop. what kind of code he has. Thus the comment is just to give him a glimpse of path need to go

Comment: @MohitShrivastava i'm with you.

Comment: You can use timerspan as well

Comment: Please provide more information and if you show your code - what did you tried you definitely will get more answers and ideas

Comment: How about with every sent email you check the time before incrementing the timer. Then you dont need fancy timer tasks

Comment: @Sebi, OP is a "She" :P, OP could you provide some code that you have worked on

Answer (score 4):

Here some raw example

```
public static class MailNumberGenerator
{
    static DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
    static int NextNumber = 1;

    public static int GetNext()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        If(CurrentDate.Date.Equals(now.Date) == false)
        {
            CurrentDate = now;
            NextNumber = 1;
        }

        return NextNumber++;
    }
}
```

This approach will reset number during same day if you restart application.
If you have running more then one instance of this application every instance will have own sequence of numbers.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Shouldn't static DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    static int nextNumber = 1; be static DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    static int _nextNumber = 1;